# how to create a multi line chart using d3 v4 without using scaleTime?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is my data.With this data I want to create multi line chart without using scaleTime.

I want my x and y-axis like
[image]

```
let data = [{
"Transaction Period":   "2018-09-11T18:30:00.000Z"
"Total Receipts":4000,
"Total Payment" :   4000
},{
"Transaction Period":   "2018-10-03T18:30:00.000Z",
"Total Receipts":   1000,
"Total Payment" :6000
},{
"Transaction Period":   "2018-10-02T18:30:00.000Z"
"Total Receipts":   8000,
"Total Payment" :20000
},{
"Transaction Period":   "2018-10-07T18:30:00.000Z",
"Total Receipts":   4000,
"Total Payment" :10000
},{
"Transaction Period":   "2018-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"Total Receipts":   12000,
"Total Payment":    12000}]
```

Comment: best to start sorting your data. Why do you not want to use scaleTime?

Comment: @rioV8 so i can print what  ever the raw value.

Comment: you somehow have to convert the time strings to something with a linear nature, then use `tickValues` and `tickFormat` to show them the way you want

Comment: @rioV8 see if my data=[{name:"alex",sales:"60"},{name:"murray",sales:"80"}] then